# Trusting non-native asset distribution

Tags: accounts, assets, trustline

If two non-issuing accounts, *x* and *y*, want to share an asset, must they trust the asset issuing account, *a*? Or can a trust line be created between *x*, *y* and a distribution account, *b*?

My (current) architecture allows for any account to issue an asset and, therefore, become *a* in the scenario above. As per suggestion of the Stellar docs, that issuing account then gives the total supply of the asset to a distribution account, *b*. If no more of that asset needs issuing, then account *a* is locked; effectively, I want to throw away *a* - hence, in my architecture, I'd like to create trust lines between *x*, *y* and *b*, and not necessarily between *x*, *y* and *a*. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `x` and `y` to trust the same asset (not issued by either `x` or `y`) then you will need an account `a` to serve as the  *issuer account*.

If you want to continue to distribute tokens issued by the *issuer account* `a` after the *issuer account* has been locked then you will need a fourth account `b` to serve as the *distributor account*, which initially holds all the tokens before distribution. This locks the total amount of tokens available.

**In this case, `x`, `y`, and `b` will need to trust the asset *issued by* `a`**. It does not make sense for `x` and `y` to *trust* `b` since `b` only *holds* the tokens, but has not *issued* them.

Comment: Hmmmm - I can't get this working! I have it so that  _x_, and _b_ trust the asset issued by _a_, but when _b_ tries to distribute to _x_, the transaction fails with the error `"op_no_trust", "tx_failed"`.

That seems to suggest that _x_ needs to trust _b_!

Comment: Note that I trying to send _ANG_ to GCITKXYYIQ3TMCBSBJGYPA5AKM4TJIKUEMC6NRSF2OP7AMZN25EML2K3 from GDFNDXPVUH2A35M5BJVTTS3ABE67ACE5IIMIHM35FZS7VXN2762QC454 on the Horizon testnet. You can confirm that they both trust the issuing account (GDCKOCW5CNPRQUNEHR3WNCLVWNBB2XXZLFNZBHD4SIPSTEJVAB7LW3D2) through the following URLs: _https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDFNDXPVUH2A35M5BJVTTS3ABE67ACE5IIMIHM35FZS7VXN2762QC454_ and _https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GCITKXYYIQ3TMCBSBJGYPA5AKM4TJIKUEMC6NRSF2OP7AMZN25EML2K3_. What am I missing?

Comment: you are not missing anything, it should work. Are you setting up the transaction correctly? Can you share the XDR of the transaction you are trying to submit?

Comment: Hey - thanks for chipping in. So I did this: `const xdr = transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR().toString("base64")`, then `console.log('Transaction XDR: ',  xdr)`. It produced this: `Transaction XDR: AAAAAMrR3fWh9A31nQprOctgCT3wCJ1CGIOzfS5l+t26/7UBAAAAZAB73jEAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAkTVfGEQ3NggyCk2Hg6BTOTShVCMF5sZF05/wMy3XSMUAAAABQU5HAAAAAADK0d31ofQN9Z0KaznLYAk98AidQhiDs30uZfrduv+1AQAAAAAU3JOAAAAAAAAAAAG6/7UBAAAAQHk1FhtO08ffJCwWQrwLoK7p3m4ramNn5c+5mywlc/D3LnFkHmfy8UDaCKck8In2ZS5nmVGG9TFzYXeoFC57BQY=`. I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Looking closer at my code, to get the asset for the payment transaction, I issue a new asset with the token code and payer as parameters: `asset = new StellarSDK.Asset(_token, _senderPublicKey)`. Is that wrong? Should it be something like `asset = new StellarSDK.Asset(_token, _issuerPublicKey)`?

Comment: Yep; by creating the asset with the issuer's public key (rather than with the sender's [public key), it worked! Boom!

Answer (score 3):

The distribution account (**b** in your case) is optional. It is handy in most cases, because asset issuing logic can be fully separated from the distribution/trading/ICO logic.

You can send your asset issued by **a** account directly to accounts **x** and **y** without any mediators. When you send custom asset from the issuing account to any other account, it issues an asset. Once the **x** account sends the asset back to the issuing account **a**, the corresponding amount of your asset is effectively destroyed.

For example, you want to issue and distribute 20 `BEER` tokens. You send 10 `BEER` tokens from **a** to accounts **x** and **y** respectively. Total number of `BEER` in circulation is 20. When account **x** sends 1 `BEER` token back to the issuing account (let's imagine, that it was consumed at the nearest pub), corresponding amount is destroyed, so now you have only 19 `BEER` tokens circulating.

Comment: But I do have the 'handy account' _b_! However, how is it **handy** if _x_ and _y_ cannot trust _b_ to do the distribution?

Comment: As I said, you can safely ignore the step with creating **b** account. If you don't need it, just don't use it. It is **optional**, the logic can be implemented without a distribution account. In your case, **x** and **y** should trust **a** directly.

Comment: Except that, if I lock the issuing account, *a* (so no more of the asset can be created), how do I then distribute the asset?

Comment: Of course, the distribution is impossible once the issuing account is locked. But the case you described (with trustlines to the distribution account instead of issuer) can't be implemented on Stellar Network.

Comment: Okay, then I'm confused! 

Maybe I should just code it and see what happens, but even if _a_ is locked, is _b_ able to distribute to _x_ and _y_, if _x_, _y_ and _b_ all trust _a_?

Comment: Yes, **b** can distribute the asset even if **a** is locked. Think of trustline as debt. Every account that want to use an asset, must trust the issuer. For example, FED (**a**) issues USD (an **asset**), and everybody, including Bank (**b**) and regular people (**x** and **y**) trust the issuer (USD is partially backed by gold).

Comment: Cool - so I take it that once _b_, _x_ and _y_ trust the asset issued by _a_, then they are free to do whatever they like with it? For instance, _b_ can send it to _x_ and _x_ can send it to _y_, etc?

Comment: Exactly. Assets can be freely transferred or traded without any limitations between any two accounts that have established trustlines to an asset.